# Import error "No module named selenium" when returning to Python project

Tags: python, selenium, import

I have a python project with Selenium that I was working on a year ago. When I came back to work on it and tried to run it I get the error `ImportError: No module named selenium`. I then ran `pip install selenium` inside the project which gave me `Requirement already satisfied: selenium in some/local/path`. How can I make my project compiler (is that the right terminology?) see my project dependencies?

Comment: What python version are you using in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're using e.g. Python 3 for your project, and selenium is installed for e.g. Python 2?
If that is the case, try `pip3 install selenium`